# Cannot upload CandyMachine to mainnet-beta - Error in arweave-bundle.ts

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine

I already tested on DevNet and I am ready to deploy on mainnet-beta with the following command

ts-node ./src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e mainnet-beta -k "C:\path\auth.json" -cp config.json -c temp ./assets

The only thing I changed from the DevNet config.json is "storage": "arweave-sol"

I am getting this error:

```
Starting upload for [3500] items, format {"mediaExt":".png","index":"0"}
1.169886324 SOL to upload 5185.453MB with buffer
Current balance 1.173224724 is sufficient.
Computed Bundle range, including 63 file pair(s) totaling 99.031MB.
Processing file groups...
Progress: [░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 0% | 0/63

upload was not successful, please re-run. TypeError: manifest.properties.files.forEach is not a function
    at getUpdatedManifest (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:330:29)
    at async processFiles (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:407:20)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:607:15)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:598:23)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:598:23)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:598:23)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:598:23)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:598:23)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:598:23)
    at async processBundleFilePair (C:\Users\captainb\Documents\GitHub\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\upload\arweave-bundle.ts:598:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `arweave-sol` in your config.json file, or make sure you change the name of the `-c`  parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yo know it was a very odd error, the same config file that worked on Devnet didn't work on Mainnet. It was that the json was malformed and had to conver the Attributes section to an array